# Navigate to AVD Manager thru eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, eclipse-juno

Supposedly to get to `AVD Manager` in Eclipse, all I have to do is clicking `Window > AVD Manager`. My problem is when I click on window, there is no `AVD Manager` among the selections. I need to edit an existing `AVD`, how would I do that? I am using `Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers. Version: Juno Service Release 2`

Initial Trick:

To the best of my knowledge, everything is installed correctly. I have already created and run my first app. But since I could not find the `AVD Manager`, I clicked `run` on the app and when eclipse complained about no existing `AVD`, I clicked on `create avd` and went from there. But now that I already have an `AVD`, I no longer get the complaint and so I am stuck with one AVD and don't know how to edit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try going to

Window-->Custom Perspective-->Command Groups Availability tab

You should see "Android SDK and AVD Manager" (mine is third one down) click the checkbox and "OK" and it should show up under "Window" now. I had to do this when I upgraded to Juno. I don't know if its something wrong in Eclipse or more likely I missed something during installation :)

Comment: And there I found `Android SDK and AVD Manager`. Thanks! (must wait 6 mins to accept)

Comment: I thought you might find it there. Glad I could help

Answer (score 1):

You might have the options for Android AVD and SDK Managers unchecked in the command group/ tool bar visibility. To get it right follow this procedure.

1. Go to Windows-> Custom Perspective
2. Under the Tool bar Visibility tab check the Android SDK and AVD Manger.
3. Under the Command Groups Availability tab, find Android SDK and AVD Manager and check it.

This will solve your problem.